# Change the style of selected objects in fabric.js

Tags: javascript, css, object, raphael, fabricjs

If u look at this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/447H3/1/)
When i click `#uploadImage` button it adds the images randomly to the `#html2canvas` div.
Now what i want is to select a specific object after adding many and then click the `#grayscale`
button to change the **object only with the selected area** to turn grayscale . is this possible using `fabric.js` or i have to change loyality ?

**HTML**

```
<div id="html2canvas">
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
</div>
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/tEpBeQV.jpg" height="50" width="50" id="my-img">
<button class="deepblue-button" id="uploadImage">Upload</button>
<button id="grayscale">GrayScale</button>
```

**JavaFabric SCRIPT**

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.setWidth(640);
canvas.setHeight(480);

var img = document.getElementById("my-img");
var upload = document.getElementById("uploadImage");

upload.addEventListener('click',uploadI,false);

function uploadI() {
    canvas.add(new fabric.Image(img, {
        left: Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + 100,
        top: Math.floor(Math.random() * 250) + 200,
        width: 100,
        height: 100
    }));
}
```

**UPDATE**

[**This Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/447H3/2/) *("Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data." presumably because of JSfiddle)* did the trick but if i am selecting multiple objects and then changing the `grayscale` it wont work . This only applies for  **one** and **only one** object selected but not multiple . Therefore anyone with a better answer ?

Comment: [This](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/447H3/2/) should do the trick, but it gives an error "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'getImageData' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The canvas has been tainted by cross-origin data." presumably because of JSfiddle?

Comment: @Tyblitz This works only for **ONE** object selected but not if multiple are selected.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I misunderstood your question. My previous fiddle indeed only changes the color of one object (the selected, active object).

If you want to have all objects grayscaled at the same time, you could push them into an array, then loop over that array to change their properties, and finally, render all of them.

```
var allImages = [],
    greyscale = document.getElementById('grayscale');

greyscale.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var filter = new fabric.Image.filters.Grayscale();
    // loop over all indexes in allImages array
    for ( var i = 0; i < allImages.length; i++ ) {
      allImages[i].filters.push(filter);
      allImages[i].applyFilters(canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
      // NB: don't know if this can be done out of the loop?
    }
}, false);

function uploadI() {
    var obj = new fabric.Image(img, {
        left: Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + 100,
        top: Math.floor(Math.random() * 250) + 200,
        width: 100,
        height: 100
    });
    // now last image added to array is at index allImages[allImages.length-1]
    allImages.push(obj);
    // now add it to the canvas
    canvas.add(allImages[allImages.length-1]);
}
```

**NB / Disclaimer:** I am not an expert in fabric.js, and although this may work, there may be better methods of doing this, eg see [`fabric.Collection`](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Collection.html), however documentation is hard to find so I hope this helps.

**NB:** Again wasn't able to test if it works because of the jsfiddle restrictions